# Span BTRFS over multiple partitions to increase disk space

Tags: btrfs

I have recently moved from a 2TB HDD with Windows 7 Enterprise (R) and several ext4 and XFS data partitions to a 4TB HDD by `dd` 'ing Windows to the new HDD.

When I wanted to create an extended partition over the left 3.5 TB the partitioner told me that I cannpt do that because MSDOS partition tables do not support such big partitions, so I created an 2TB btrfs partition (with several subvolumes for my data) and a 1.5TB extended partition.

Now I have an 900GB btrfs partition and a 2TB btrfs partition, how can I "join" the disk space. I thought that this would be possible using `btrfs device add`, however this seems to use RAID0, so I would essentialy loose some disk space, because 2*900GB = 1.8TB, while I already have 2TB.

Is there a way to add the second disk, so that I get 2.9TB disk space?

[image: My Disk Setup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your BTRFS defaulted to the `raid0` mode when adding a new device; you can change it to `single` mode by running `btrfs balance start -dconvert=single,soft /mountpoint`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can you provide a link to some documentation where one can read a bit more about that feature?

Comment: Sure, the best info on BTRFS can be found on the official wiki: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Conversion https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Balance_Filters

Comment: Well the official wiki does not describe what `single` actually means.

Comment: "The option -m single means that no duplication is done (...)"